# Remove text formatting from chapter title

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

I'm having a problem with the chapter headings formatting. 
I would like to change only the first letter of each chapter, but for the lists of figures and tables chapters it's not working.

Here is the example:

[image: Generated pdf]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\font\chapterTextFont = Rothdn scaled 4500 \relax
\def\splitfirstchar#1#2\sentinel{
  \chapterTextFont\uppercase{#1}\LARGE\uppercase{#2}}
\def\chapterText#1{\splitfirstchar#1\sentinel}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{}{1em}{\chapterText}


\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\chapter{Testing title}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Might be possible to fix this problem by removing the text formatting of `\listfigurename` and save in another variable, but I do not know how to do this.

========= Edit 2013/01/19 ========

Simplest solution found by *Ulrike Fischer* (Thank you!)

Just change:

```
\def\chapterText#1{\splitfirstchar#1\sentinel}
```

to:

```
\def\chapterText#1{\expandafter\splitfirstchar#1\sentinel}
```

And also thank you *Gonzalo Medina* and *karlkoeller* both answers worked too.

Comment: Put \expandafter before the \splitfirstchar in \chapterText

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you please make it an answer? It is by far the best solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an expansion problem. Without explicitly rewriting `\listfigurename` (and other predefined names such as `\listtablename`), you can do

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\font\chapterTextFont = Rothdn scaled 4500 \relax
\expandafter\def\expandafter\splitfirstchar#1#2\sentinel{
  \chapterTextFont\expandafter\uppercase{#1}\LARGE\uppercase{#2}}
\def\chapterText#1{\splitfirstchar#1\sentinel}

\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\chapter*{\listfigurename}}{\chapter*{\expandafter\expandafter\chapterText{\listfigurename}}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\chapter*{\listtablename}}{\chapter*{\expandafter\expandafter\chapterText\listtablename}}{}{}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{}{1em}{\chapterText}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Testing title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @HarishKumar Hi, Harish. I missed you all too :-) I'll try to be around here a little more, if I can.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}
  {\chapter*{\listfigurename}}
  {\chapter*{List of Figures}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}
  {\chapter*{\listtablename}}
  {\chapter*{List of Tables}}
  {}
  {}
```

In this way we patch `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` so to use the expanded names, and this is the result (I've added `\thechapter` to `\titleformat` just in case you wanted, remove it if you don't want it):

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\font\chapterTextFont = Rothdn scaled 4500 \relax
\def\splitfirstchar#1#2\sentinel{
  \chapterTextFont\uppercase{#1}\LARGE\uppercase{#2}}
\def\chapterText#1{\splitfirstchar#1\sentinel}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\Huge\thechapter}{1em}{\chapterText}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}
  {\chapter*{\listfigurename}}
  {\chapter*{List of Figures}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}
  {\chapter*{\listtablename}}
  {\chapter*{List of Tables}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\chapter{Testing title}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```