# How can I remove text formatting for the title of tableofcontents that is used for chapter titles?

Tags: table-of-contents, books

I'm having trouble formatting the table of contents. I would like to change only the first page, but for the other pages it is not working.
Here is the example:[image]

Here's the code

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\font\chapterTextFont = Rothdn scaled 4500 \relax
\def\splitfirstchar#1#2\sentinel{
  \chapterTextFont\uppercase{#1}\LARGE\uppercase{#2}}
\def\chapterText#1{\splitfirstchar#1\sentinel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\Huge\thechapter}{1em}{\chapterText}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\chapter*{\contentsname}}
  {\chapter*{\chapterText{Contents}}}
  {}
  {}

\patchcmd{\listoffigures}
  {\chapter*{\listfigurename}}
  {\chapter*{List of Figures}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}
  {\chapter*{\listtablename}}
  {\chapter*{List of Tables}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\expandafter\chapterText{Contents}}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\chapter{Testing title}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not an example that others can test. Please extend your example to something others can copy and test as is.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154440/remove-text-formatting-from-chapter-title